# Why do I get the same output for DateTime.now.in_time_zone(-4) and DateTime.now.in_time_zone(-3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The result of this:

```
> DateTime.now.in_time_zone(-3)
=> Wed, 11 Jul 2018 11:33:00 -03 -03:00
```

appears to be the same as this:

```
> DateTime.now.in_time_zone(-4)
=> Wed, 11 Jul 2018 11:33:02 ADT -03:00
```

Why am I getting the same time for two different time zones?

Comment: Ok, what does `DateTime.now.zone` return? Show output of `DateTime.now` and `DateTime.now.in_time_zone(-4)`

Comment: `Wed, 11 Jul 2018 10:33:55 -0400` and `Wed, 11 Jul 2018 11:34:12 ADT -03:00` respectively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [`in_time_zone`](https://apidock.com/rails/DateAndTime/Zones/in_time_zone) source code, it relies on `Time.find_zone!`:

```
Time.find_zone!(-3) #=> "Brasilia"
Time.find_zone!(-4) #=> "Atlantic Time (Canada)"
```

Due to the wonders of time change (sarcasm?), this time of year, Brasilia and Atlantic Time share the same time at `-3`:

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/brasilia
[image]
https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/canada/halifax
[image]